# How to get absolute url in Pylons?

Tags: python, routes, pylons

How to get absolute url in Pylons ?

Comment: Aren't URLs already absolute...? (read: you need to be much more specific.)

Comment: Sorry (: I mean domain name. Like "stackoverflow.com"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To generate a fully qualified URL with Routes, use `qualified=True` keyword in `url()` call.

Example:

```
print url("blog", id=123, qualified=True)  
# depending on routing configuration,
# would print something like "http://somehost/blog/123"
```

If your web application is running behind load balancer or reverse proxy, you might get into issues where generated URLs point to backend appservers not the frontend proxy / load balancer. You can use `host` argument to correct for that:

```
print url("blog", id=123, qualified=True, host="example.com")  
# ==> "http://example.com/blog/123"
```

Refer to [Routes manual](http://routes.groovie.org/manual.html) for more options and tweaks.

Comment: Thanks (: I use h.url("/", qualified=True) for my problem.